# How to multiply the values of a map by the values of another map functionally in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have two maps `quantity,price` of type `Map[String, Int]`.

`Price` has many items and their prices and `quantity` have the items that
I have and their quantity.
I'm trying to have a function that will return the total value of the Items that I have, I did it like this but I feel there's an improvement that can be done so it can be more functional.

```
def value (quantity: Map[String,Int], price: Map[String,Int]): Int = {
    var value = 0
    quantity.foreach { case (item,qunatity) =>
      value+= price(item) * qunatity
    }
    value
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you do mapping and `.sum` rather than mutating?

```
quantity.map { case item -> quantity =>
  price(item) * quantity
}.sum
```

Please notice that this throws if a key from `quantity` is absent in `price`.

You can consider

```
(quantity.keySet intersect price.keySet)
  .map(item => quantity(item) * price(item))
  .sum
```

Although maybe throwing is a desirable semantics, otherwise items with unknown price are for free.

Comment: thank you, I was thinking of this but didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, `foldLeft` may be a bit more concise than map + sum in this case.

```
   quantity.foldLeft(0) { case (p, (i, q)) => p + price.getOrElse(i, 0)*q }
```

Comment: You also have goods with unknown price for free :)